# Not able to compress js and css file using YUI compress

Tags: maven

I have written following script in my pom.xml file and i am getting error in one js file saying "missing name after . operator"

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compress_js_css</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compress</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>src/main/js/*.js</exclude>
            <exclude>src/main/css/*.css</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <jswarn>false</jswarn>
        <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Someone please suggest me how to Compress js and css file using MVN YUI Compressor i have used above mentioned script in pom.xml but this is not working.

Comment: Where are your js located ?

Comment: js is inside src/main/js folder

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late to answer this, but I thought that it may help someone else. 
It might be because of improper use of some of the Java script reserved words in your javascript file. You might have tried to access some property value of an object using '.' operator which belongs to reserved key set. So when you run YUI compress it will automatically throw this error